# How to set multiple absoluted divs on right side of the body (relative to each other)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating facebook like chat boxes.In friends list as I select on one user a chat box is open.But I am using following css for chat box.

```css
  .chat_box{ 
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  right:20px;
  width:250px;
  background-color:white;
  border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;

}
```

I am using right:20px; but if I open multiple chat boxes then I will have to set this right property again and again after calculation.
How can I open mulitple chat boxes with no hard-coded positions.

Comment: please, provide the rest of your code

Comment: obvious way is let them flow within an outer container and only set outer container fixed

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear. Snippet is not loading for me. I hope it will help you.

```
.chat_box
            {
                width: 250px;
                position: fixed;
                height: 100%;
                right: 20px;
                top: 0px;
                padding-top: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
                border: 1px solid white;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `position:fixed` on the container, and then put boxes inside with `float:left`

[Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gE3An2Jk14jQNG3loyPB?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for code for multiple fixed.

```
<div class='chatbox-group'>

<div class='chat_box'>
</div>
<div class='chat_box'>
</div>

</div>

Css for this


.chatbox-group
{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
 }  
.chat_box{ 
   float:right;
   margin-right:20px;
   width:250px;
   background-color:white;
   border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant set multiple absolute divs, which will be aligned automatically, but You can create one absolute div, which contains other, static containers.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovuLfofc/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="chats-container">

    <div class="chat_box">
        First box
    </div>
    <div class="chat_box">
        Second box
    </div>
    <div class="chat_box">
        Third box
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#chats-container {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    right:20px;
    width:250px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}
.chat_box{ 
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 24px 0px;
    float: left;
}
```